# If $G$ satisfies the maximal condition is it finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that a group $G$ satisfies the maximal condition if and only if every subgroup of $G$ is finitely generated.
So I think that if $G$  satisfies the maximal condition then it is finitely generated because $G$ is a subgroup of itself.
Am I right or not?

Comment: Correctamundo. ${}{}$

Comment: i can't understand what does amundo mean?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=correctamundo).

Comment: @MerieMarissa It's a way of saying "correct".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, indeed, $G$ is a subgroup of itself.

On the other hand, you could have groups so that every ${\it proper}$ subgroup is finitely generated, while $G$ itself is not. An example would be to consider a prime number and the $G$ the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}_p/ \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Q}_p$ consists of all rational numbers with denominator a power of $p$.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Pedro Tamaroff in the comments, you are correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/549254)

Comment: @StellaBiderman it's a community wiki... Spend a few seconds reading, while reviewing.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't see that when going through the review queue.